# Azure Webjob - Error While Deploying Scheduled Job

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am trying to upload a Webjob to my Azure Website via Web-Deploy but I'm getting the following error:

`An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: An error occurred while sending the request.`

Any ideas? (I'm a co-administrator of the subscription)

Webjob Settings: `{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "WebJob1",
  "startTime": "2014-12-22T00:00:00+02:00",
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Hour",
  "interval": 1,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}`

Answer (score 0):

So. I had exactly this problem. The webjob would not publish with my website. Turns out I had an existing publish profile to a different web-app set on the webjob project itself.

This is what I did:

- From the azure portal, I deleted the old scheduler collection and the old web app.
- Then I deleted the publish profiles folder from the webjob's project (in the Properties folder).
- Finally, I re-published the website and, hey-presto, the webjob published.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any other significance about the occurence of errer ?

Hope [this post](http://www.nguyenquyhy.com/2014/10/an-error-occurred-while-creating-the-webjob-schedule/) will be help.